Google Apps Script активная яейчка getActiveRange
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема — при обращении к книге по URL или ID не отрабатывает функция getActiveRange().
При установке в любую ячейку в варианте с URL или ID всегда позиция 1,1.
При обращении через getActiveSpreadsheet() — getActiveRange показывает правильно.
Мой код:
function myFunction() {

  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName ("111");

  const ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1XmeCyPbI____i_______Hes");
  const sheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("111");


  var range1 = sheet1.getActiveRange();
  var range2 = sheet2.getActiveRange();

  var col1 = range1.getColumn ();
  var row1 = range1.getRow ();

  var col2 = range2.getColumn ();
  var row2 = range2.getRow ();

  Logger.log (col1);
  Logger.log (row1);

  Logger.log (col2);
  Logger.log (row2);
}


Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками

Все дело в контексте. Используя getActiveSpreadsheet() вы получаете ссылку на текущую таблицу. И все функции будут использоваться в контексте текущей таблицы.

Functions that are run in the context of a spreadsheet can get a
reference to the corresponding Spreadsheet object by calling this
function.

Используя функции open(file) , openById(id) и openByUrl(url) вы получаете ссылку на новую открытую таблицу на сервере.

Note that the spreadsheet doesn't physically open on the client side.
It opens on the server only (for modification by the script).


"вы получаете ссылку на новую открытую таблицу на сервере" - Ох

Как более правильно написать?
